# Save User Categories in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I've been following along with the following tutorial [How to Add User Taxonomy in WordPress](https://www.nopio.com/blog/add-user-taxonomy-wordpress/)
, my issue is that the user categories do not save.  I want to be able to add categories to the users for filtering capabilities.

Here is my function for saving:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'ru_admin_save_user_categories' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'ru_admin_save_user_categories' );


function ru_admin_save_user_categories( $user_id ) {
    $tax = get_taxonomy( USER_CATEGORY_NAME );
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

if ( !user_can( $user, 'administrator' ) ) {
    return false;
}

$new_categories_ids = $_POST[USER_CATEGORY_META_KEY];
$user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, USER_CATEGORY_META_KEY, true );
$previous_categories_ids = array();

if( !empty( $user_meta ) ) {
    $previous_categories_ids = (array)$user_meta;
}

if( ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && $_POST['role'] != 'author' ) ) {
    delete_user_meta( $user_id, USER_CATEGORY_META_KEY );
    ru_update_users_categories_count( $previous_categories_ids, array() );
} else {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, USER_CATEGORY_META_KEY, $new_categories_ids );
    ru_update_users_categories_count( $previous_categories_ids, $new_categories_ids );
}
}
```

Upon submitting nothing happens and I do not see the data saved in user meta either.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, and after a lot of digging and searching I found this plugin I'm using in my project called [LH user taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lh-user-taxonomies/), and the way they save the terms in a user is using the following function.

```
function set_terms_for_user( $user_id, $taxonomy, $terms = array(), $bulk = false ) {

    // Get the taxonomy
    $tax = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

    // Make sure the current user can edit the user and assign terms before proceeding.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) && current_user_can( $tax->cap->assign_terms ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( empty( $terms ) && empty( $bulk ) ) {
        $terms = isset( $_POST[ $taxonomy ] )
            ? $_POST[ $taxonomy ]
            : null;
    }

    // Delete all user terms
    if ( is_null( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
        wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $user_id, $taxonomy );

    // Set the terms
    } else {
        $_terms = array_map( 'sanitize_key', $terms );

        // Sets the terms for the user
        wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, $_terms, $taxonomy, false );
    }

    // Clean the cache
    clean_object_term_cache( $user_id, $taxonomy );
}
```

Generally the main part where they save the terms with the user is using a WordPress function called

```
wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, $_terms, $taxonomy, false );
```

You should look into the plugin if you have other questions or maybe just use it in your project.